# Recursive Collatz Function in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, collatz

In order to count the number of times the Collatz conjecture must be implemented in order to get the result 1, I implemented a recursive counter function which uses two parameters, specifically the number and the counter.

```
unsigned int count_collatz_rec(int num, unsigned int count) {
    if(num == 1){
        count = count + 0;
    }
    else{
        count++;
        num = collatz(num);
        count = count_collatz_rec(num, count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Is there any way to implement this function by using only one parameter, specifically 'num'?

Comment: Unrelated: `if(num == 1) { count = count + 0; } else { ...` would be better written as `if(num != 1) { ...`

Comment: The answer is certainly positive. But for now, can you add to your question the implementation of `collatz`?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this could work:

```
  unsigned int count_collatz_rec(int num)
  {
        return (num <= 1) ? 1 : 1 + count_collatz_rec(collatz(num));
  }
```

Comment: Even though that's what OP seems to want - I'm beginning to think that you had it right before I interfered - although starting with 0 could be a case to return 0 as some sort of error. [Example using your original formula](https://godbolt.org/z/dK1K41) Nevertheless, the solution seems sound no matter what base OP wants. It's easy enough to correct it if needed.

Comment: yeah, it's easy to adopt. it would be good to get some feedback first, because no complete main file is presented in OP.